# Consider a random sample of size n from a uniform distribution, $X_i - UNIF(0,θ), θ>0$ and $X_{n:n}$ is the largest order statistic

Tags: self-study, confidence-interval, uniform-distribution

Consider a random sample of size n from a uniform distribution, $X_i - UNIF(0,θ), θ>0$ and $X_{n:n}$ is the largest order statistic.

1. What is the probability that $(X_{n:n}, 2X_{n:n})$ contains $θ$?
2. Find a constant k where $(x_{n:n}, kx_{n:n})$ is a $100(1-a)$%
   confidence interval for $θ$.

Comment: Maybe you should first work out the distribution function of $X_{n:n}$: then you would have the basis for answering these questions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Question has been tagged as self-study. Here's a hint:

As @whuber points out, both of these questions can be solved by solved by finding the distribution of the maximum order statistic. In general, the cdf of the maximum order statistic is given by the following (Equation 4.2.3 from [Mukhopahyay 2000](https://books.google.com/books/about/Probability_and_Statistical_Inference.html?id=TMSnGkr_DxwC)):

$$ P(X_{n:n} \le y) = P(X_i \le y \mathrm{\ for\ each \ } i = 1, ..., n)$$
$$ = \prod_{i=1}^n P(X_i \le y) = \{ F(y) \}^n $$

and the pdf is given by taking the derivative of the last expression (eqn 4.2.4 Mukhopadhyay):

$$ g(y) = \frac{d}{dy} [\{ F(y) \}^n] = n \{ F(y) \}^{n-1} f(y) $$

For the uniform distribution, $f(y) = \theta^{-1} $ for $ 0 < y < \theta $ and $ F(y) = \frac{y}{\theta} $ for $ 0 < y < \theta $. We easily plug these in to find the pdf of the order statistic $X_{n:n}$:
$$ g(y) = ny^{n-1}\theta^{-n} $$.

From there you should be able to find  $P(X_{n:n} \le \theta \le 2X_{n:n})$ and solve for $k$ in $P(X_{n:n} \le \theta \le kX_{n:n}) = (1-\alpha) $

Comment: +1.  It occurs to me there's solution that uses the same ideas but needs less machinery.  Since $X_{n:n}$ is sure not to exceed $\theta$, we only need to use the independence assumption to work out $$\Pr(kX_{n:n}\ge\theta)=\Pr(X_{n:n}\ge\theta/k)=1-\Pr(X_{n:n}\lt\theta/k) = 1-\prod_{i=1}^n\Pr(X_i\lt\theta/k)$$ and the rest is simple.

Comment: @whuber Yes, definitely simpler. Looks like you lost the $k$ in the last step though. Shouldn't it be $1-\prod_{i=1}^n P(X_i < \frac{\theta}{k} )$?